# Magento 2.3.2 An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkencryptionencryptor(alias: Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor)

Tags: error, installation, magento2.3.2

During the installation of **Magento 2.3.2** an error appears when creating an admin account:

> An abstract factory could not create an instance of
>   magentoframeworkencryptionencryptor(alias:
>   Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor).

The PHP version is 7.2.3

[image]

Please help

Comment: did you try running setup again?

Comment: Yes, three times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your libsodium version to match the requirement, which is  version 1.0.13 or above.

Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt install php-libsodium
```

CentOS:

```
$ yum install php-pecl-libsodium2
```

Restart your web-server.

After installing libsodium, make sure that it is loaded:

```
$ php -i | grep libsodium
libsodium headers version => 1.0.17
libsodium library version => 1.0.17
```

If you get another error such as `PHP Fatal error: sodium_init() in Unknown on line 0`, you should try installing libsodium using PECL. But for now at least you should try installing it using apt/yum first.

Comment: It works, thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that!