# Error installing Magento 2.3.2: An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkencryptionencryptor

Tags: magento2, php-7, docker

I am installing magento 2 via a docker image :

> quay.io/alexcheng1982/apache2-php7:7.2.12

I keep getting this message:

```
 An abstract factory could not create an instance of 
magentoframeworkencryptionencryptor(alias: 

Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor).
```

[image]

I understand from this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/281526/41747) that the issue is caused by not having php-libsodium installed in my **apache** image

Consequently,following this [comment](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/540), I added **libsodium** to the image:

I.e ;

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libsodium-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install sodium
```

However I am still getting the error.

I checked my **phpinfo()** and indeed sodium has been added:

**PHPINFO PAGE;**

```
     sodium
sodium support  enabled
libsodium headers version   1.0.8
libsodium library version   1.0.8
```

Two question:

Is this indeed the cause of the problem?

If so, could the reason for the failure be that I did not install the latest version of libsodium. I note from the other question that version 1.0.17 was installed and this seemed to do the trick.

the version I installed is: 1.0.8

this is how i installed version 1.0.8

```
RUN apt-get update -y
    RUN apt-get install libsodium-dev -y
    RUN docker-php-ext-install sodium
```

is there a way to install a later version ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Magento Release Notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.2OpenSource.html)

The security enhancements that are part of Magento 2.3.2 require the installation of libsodium version 1.0.13 or higher. You will not be able to successfully install Magento Commerce 2.3.2 without first ensuring that your server runs version 1.0.13 or higher.

Also you can review  comments on the github issue 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23405, it describe how to update libsodium in different distro

Also, you can build it by self
https://github.com/jreckner/docker-libsodium/blob/master/Dockerfile